# Find the cluster points: For each cluster point, find a sub-sequence converging to it.

Tags: real-analysis, clustering

The book I am using for my Advance Calculus course is Introduction to Analysis by Arthur Mattuck.

Find the cluster points of:

(a). {${sin(\frac{n+1}{n} \frac{n}{2})}$}

(b). {${sin(n+\frac{n}{2})\frac{\pi}{2}}$}

For each cluster point, find a sub-sequence converging to it.

This is my rough proof to this question. I was wondering if anybody can look over it and see if I made a mistake or if there is a simpler way of doing this problem. I want to thank you ahead of time it is greatly appreciated.So lets begin.

Proof:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you understand the problem, but let me write the answer in a more practical way.

(a) Your sequence is $ \sin \big( \frac{n+1}{n } \frac{\pi}{2}  \big) $ is covergent, the set of the cluster point is  $ \{  \sin \big( \frac{n+1}{n } \frac{\pi}{2}  \big)  , n \in  \mathbb{N}\}  \cup  \{ 1\}$. To find a sunsequence for each one is an easy task.

(b) In this case, your sequence is  $ \sin \big( \frac{3n}{2 } \frac{\pi}{2}  \big)  $,  This sequence has three [subsequential limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequential_limit)  $ \{ -1,0, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \}$, hence it is divergent.  The set of cluster points is $ \{  \sin \big( \frac{3n+}{2n } \frac{\pi}{2}  \big)  , n \in  \mathbb{N}\}  \cup   \{ -1,0, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \}$  . To find the subsequences of these cluter points you may take $ n= 4k, \;  4k+1, \; 4k+2$ respectively.